# What is this canoe-shaped rock with obsidian? flakes?

Tags: geology

I found this rock near my home in the high desert of south central Utah (near Capitol Reef National Park). The sides are symmetrical and smooth -- shaped somewhat like a canoe. It is 6 1/2" long; 1 1/2" at widest point. The top is sheared off and sparkles in the light. It is embedded with flakes of a shiny, black glasslike material, possibly obsidian. The Fremont culture occupied the area and left an abundance of tools, points, and chip rock, many of which were sourced from elsewhere; most likely the result of trading. A neighbor and I came up with an uninformed theory. Would appreciate any informed observations.
[image]

Comment: Do you have more photo's, preferably out of direct sunlight? This one is oversaturated. And any more information [mentioned here](http://meta.earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/124/a-guide-for-asking-identify-this-rock-questions)?

Comment: I don't think the black stuff is obsidian. It definitely looks like crystals, possibly phenocrysts of amphibole or pyroxene.

Comment: the shape could be due to wind based weathering, it often produces smooth sided angular ventifacts. https://www.researchgate.net/figure/284360115_fig1_Figure-1-A-the-three-mature-shapes-of-small-ventifacts-predicted-by-the-model-described

Answer (score 4):

Black elongated crystals are mostly hornblendes. The rock itself is (probably) horblende andersite or hornblende dacite. Both are intermediate volcanic rocks.